# Linked List and Pointers in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi guys I'm learning C and I'm having trouble understanding this code:

```
struct node {
int data;
int key;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

//delete a link with given key
struct node* delete(int key) {

//start from the first link
struct node* current = head;
struct node* previous = NULL;

//if list is empty
if(head == NULL) {
  return NULL;
}

//navigate through list
while(current->key != key) {

  //if it is last node
  if(current->next == NULL) {
     return NULL;
  } else {
     //store reference to current link
     previous = current;
     //move to next link
     current = current->next;
  }
}
//found a match, update the link
if(current == head) {
   //change first to point to next link
   head = head->next;
} else {
   //bypass the current link
   previous->next = current->next;
}    

return current;
}
```

The code is actually working , it is removing elements from the linked list in C but I don't understand how if we're not touching the head struct variable (Here is my trouble):

```
//bypass the current link
   previous->next = current->next;
```

I do understand the code but I don't understand how the variable head is gonna change if we don't do head=something.

Also, how it's posible to have two variables with the same name (current)

Thanks

Btw I found the code here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_program_in_c.htm

Comment: Because you have omitted the function definitions in the tutorial and posted nonsensical inline code.

Comment: You really miss part of function. See the tutorial in more detail. The part you have here only finds the one to delete. The code bellow it does the deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the code is posted does not work, because it indeed misses deletion of the initial node in the `head` pointer. However, you omitted some code which apparently fixes the problem. Here is the code from the original `delete`:

```
//found a match, update the link
if(current == head) {
    //change first to point to next link
    head = head->next;
} else {
    //bypass the current link
    previous->next = current->next;
}
```

This is where the code adjusts the head pointer after deletion. The only issue with this code is that it never calls `free` anywhere in the body of the tutorial, but unfortunately, errors like that are common both on free web sites and in book.

Here is an implementation that does the same thing with a single double-pointer:

```
struct node* delete(int key) {
    struct node** ptrCurrent = &head;
    while (*ptrCurrent) {
        if ((*ptrCurrent)->key == key) {
            struct node* tmp = *ptrCurrent;
            *ptrCurrent = (*ptrCurrent)->next;
            free(tmp);
            break;
        }
        ptrCurrent = &((*ptrCurrent)->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like que best anwser. Excuse me sir, what are the two ** after node?

Comment: @Edw4rd That's a pointer to pointer declaration. Walk through the code to see how it works: it points to `head` first, then it moves to point to the `next` of the first node, then to the `next` of the second node, and so on. This lets you assign a pointer to `head` or to `next` without knowing which one you are assigning.

Answer (score 0):

For a struct a->b accesses what is stored in b in struct a. This means the line current=current->next is in effect saying set current equal to what is stored in the next variable in the the struct current. In other words, go to the next item in the list.

Comment: I'm sorry I messed up and missed some parts of the function , Can you read my question again please?

Comment: This doesnt change the explanation of current-> next. As for the second part i dont belive you have two different variables. struct node *current = NULL; is saying take the struct of note type named current and make it null, not re-declare it.

Answer (score 0):

For the line

```
previous->next = current->next;
```

The `previous` variable has address of previous item in linked list. It can have address of `head` as any other item.

You just set the next item is the one behind. Similar to:

You dont have to change `head` if you delete any item in list (except first - the `head` and the second).